# Accessing class variables from form validator method in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I'm trying to build a modal driven form with custom validation.
I want to Validate that the password the user insert answer the requirements (Uppercase latter,lowercase latter and number).
The issue is that I don't want to write the regex especially in the method,I want to have an ineluctable service that concentrate all of my regex.
I was able to inject the service to the component class but couldn't in any way access to the service instance inside the validetor method.

Any one has any idea how can I access the service?

Thanks.

This is my code :

```
export class SignUpComponent implements OnInit {
regexService:RegexService
  builder: FormBuilder
  signUpForm: FormGroup;
  email: FormControl;
  password: FormControl;
  passwordAgain: FormControl;


  matchedPassword (input: any) {
    if(!input.root || !input.root.controls)
    return null;

    if(input.root.controls.password.value===input.root.controls.passwordAgain.value)
      return null;
    else
      return { mismatchedPassword: true };
   }

   passwordAnswerRequirements(input: any){
     if(!input.root || !input.root.controls)
     return null;

     if(this.regexService.getRegex('password').test(input.value))
        return null;
      else
        return {notAcceptablePassword:true}
   }



  constructor(builder: FormBuilder,regexService:RegexService) {
    this.builder=builder;
    this.regexService=regexService;
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.email = new FormControl('', [
       Validators.required,
    ]);
     this.password = new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        this.matchedPassword,
        this.passwordAnswerRequirements
     ]);
     this.passwordAgain=new FormControl('',[
        Validators.required,
        this.matchedPassword,
        this.passwordAnswerRequirements
     ]);
     this.signUpForm = this.builder.group({
       email: this.email,
       password: this.password,
       passwordAgain:this.passwordAgain
     });
  }
```

My service name is 'RegexService' and the validetor function name is 'passwordAnswerRequirements'

Comment: your code is missing the keyword `class`

Comment: I had is..Just didnt copy it to here... Ive edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution.. It's not the most aesthetic one, but it works...
I add a wrap function around the 'passwordAnswerRequirements' method and from there I was able to grab the service instance in put it in a local variable.

```
  passwordAnswerRequirements() {
    let passwordRegexExp = this.regexService.getRegex('password');
    return (input: any) => {
      if (!input.root || !input.root.controls)
        return null;
      if (passwordRegexExp.test(input.value))
        return null;
      else
        return { notAcceptablePassword: true }
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare your service variable, it's already in the constructor and you can use it as `this.regexService` inside your class, so

```
export class SignUpComponent implements OnInit {
//regexService:RegexService  -- remove this line
  builder: FormBuilder
  signUpForm: FormGroup;
  email: FormControl;
  password: FormControl;
  passwordAgain: FormControl;



  constructor(builder: FormBuilder,private regexService:RegexService) {
    this.builder=builder;
   // this.regexService=regexService; -- you don't need this line
  }
....
```